# com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized in google drive service account

Tags: google-drive-api

Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("gdriveconnector@testconnector-205108.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                //  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("/GoogleDriveSrvcAcnt-4d4a3f9e9059.p12"))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(serviceAccountPrivateKey)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
                .setServiceAccountUser("user@sdfj.com")
                .build();

I am passing email id of admin in account user still this error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using either an [expired or invalid token access token](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials).

> Suggested action: Refresh the access token using the long-lived
>   refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow,
>   as described in [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).

Comment: I tried with a fresh token still the issue persisted.I am looking for user impersonation so oauth think won''t work